# adding a Download feature in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to provide the download option for the flutter app,

here I am hitting the rest API , which gives the response like below

```
{
    "headers": {
        "name": "name",
        "c": "c",
        "java": "java",
        "flutter": "flutter"
    },
    "total": 3101, //total records inside that report

    "data": [
        {
            "Reg No": "1XX19XX400",
            "name": "abc",
            "c": "91",
            "java": "81",
            "flutter": "71"
        },
{
            "Reg No": "1XX19XX401", //It wont be present in header section bcz we keep it as a default
            "name": "xyz",
            "c": "90",
            "java": "60",
            "flutter": "70"
        },
{
            "Reg No": "1XX19XX402",
            "name": "pqr",
            "c": "88",
            "java": "78",
            "flutter": "98"
        }
... remaining records.
]
}
```

once download is clicked I want to write this on excel sheet something like below,

```
Reg.No name c java flutter
1XX19XX400 abc 91 81 71
1XX19XX401 xyz 90 60 70
```

so a file should gets downloaded in the phone once download is clicked.

can anybody help me by giving the approach to do the same or any helpful information for adding this feature.

Comment: I think "download" is the wrong word for this. You would like to create a local excel file with the response from the api and save it somewhere else. Right?

Comment: Hi @thmspl , in my flutter App I am displaying multiple reports which once clicked it will hit the API and display the result in the data table, but I am trying to provide a download option, like on report card there would be a download icon, which once clicked I want to write the result of the api to a excel file, and its get downloaded and stored in the /download directory in that smartphone.